# Is there any rational reason to use a double to store an integer when precision loss isn't acceptable?

Tags: c

I'm learning C from K&R (Second Edition) and am confused by one of the book's early examples. In section 1.5.2, the book first exhibits a character-counting program that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

and then remarks:

> It may be possible to cope with even bigger numbers by using a `double`

and exhibits this alternative version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 2nd version */
main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Does using a `double` here make any sense? It doesn't seem to; surely a `long long` would be superior, since it can store bigger integers than a double can (without loss of precision) in the same space and helps readability by conveying at declaration time that the variable is an integer.

Is there some justification for using a `double` here that I'm missing, or is the K&R example just plain bad code that's been shoehorned in to demonstrate the `double` type?

Comment: At the time K&R was written (1978) `long long` didn't exist. Thus they wouldn't have used it.

Comment: `long long` didn't exist when the book was written. (2nd edition was 1989)

Comment: `long long` was only introduced in C99.

Comment: Remember that `long long` wasn't standardized until C99, and until maybe fifteen years ago 64 bit integral types weren't so commonly available even as an extension on many compilers. Also, even if present on 32 bit machines their operations had to be emulated in software, while operations on double historically is efficiently implemented in hardware on many platforms (on x86, in particular, hardware support is always available since the 486, and was a common addition since before the 386).

Comment: I think a double would be able to store larger digits than a long long due to the fact it can represent an exponent of up to 1023, wheres a long long would only go as high as maybe 128? 256? (at most). But you're right, it wouldn't have the same precision.

Comment: The `double` has to be taken with a grain of salt. It's true that it offers something like 52 bits of integer, which may be more than any of the available integral types, something curious happens when you reach that value: At that point, adding 1 has no effect, and the number just stays the same forever. So you should establish the maximal value at which a `double` has unit precision and check against that for "overflow" in your loop.

Comment: @KerrekSB At the time it was written I don't think there were many 64-bit operating systems. And a file whose size would overflow a 52-bit mantissa was also pretty unlikely.

Comment: @Barmar: Who's talking about file sizes? A C FILE doesn't have a size :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB the code snippets from K&R are for counting the number of characters in a file - hence the relevance of Barmar's comment.

Comment: It's reading from stdin. That's likely to be either a file or the user typing. I wouldn't want to have to type more than 2^52 characters.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you have to check for overflow anyway, using two `unsigned long`s and implement a proper 64 bit counter is the much more intelligent solution anyway. But OP should really get a more modern book to learn C. No wonder there still is so much outdated&rubbish code which makes the bad reputation C has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `double` vs. `long`

> Is there any rational reason to use a double to store an integer when precision loss isn't acceptable?
>   [...] Does using a double here make any sense?

Even in C2011, type `long` may have as few as 31 value bits, so its range of representable values may be as small as from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 (supposing two's complement representation; slightly narrower with sign/magnitude representation).

C does not specify details of the representation of floating-point values, but IEEE-754 representation is near-universal nowadays.  C `double`s are almost always represented in IEEE-754 binary double precision format, which provides 53 bits of mantissa.  That format can exactly represent all integers from -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) to 2<sup>53</sup> - 1, and arithmetic involving those numbers will be performed exactly if it is performed according to IEEE specifications and if the mathematical result and all intermediate values are exactly representable integers (and sometimes even when not).

So using `double` instead of `long` could indeed yield a much greater numeric range without sacrificing precision.

#### `double` vs. `long long`

> surely a `long long` would be superior [...]

`long long` has a larger range of (exactly) representable integer values than `double`, and therefore there is little reason to prefer `double` over `long long` for integers if the latter is available. However, as has been observed in comments, `long long` did not exist in 1978 when the first edition of K&R was published, and it was far from standard even in 1988 when the second edition was published.  Therefore, `long long` was not among the alternatives Kernighan and Ritchie were considering.  Indeed, although many C90 compilers eventually supported it as an extension, `long long` was not standardized until C99.

In any case, I'm inclined to think that the remark that confused you was not so much an endorsement of using `double` for the purpose, as a sidebar comment about the comparative range of `double`.

Comment: The C standard does list some requirements for values to be held in `double` without loss of precision. For example all integers of up to 10 decimal digits must be storable. (which is a wider range than a 32-bit int)

Comment: @M.M, there is C2011 5.2.4.2.2, describing `float.h` and its contents.  Is that what you mean?  Its requirements are not couched in quite the terms you present, but I agree that it has the practical effect of establishing minimum ranges of exactly-representable integer values for each floating-point type.  IEEE double precision greatly exceeds those minimums, though, so it serves as a more dramatic example.

Answer (score 2):

In the old 32-bit computer, using "long long" is more expensive than "double". because using "long long" each 64-bit integer addition needs to be computed by 2 CPU instructions: "ADD" & "ADC". But by using "double" only one FPU addition is enough to increment the counter. And from the IEEE-754 standard, "double" has a precision of 53 bit (1-bit sign + 11 bit exponent + (52+1 implicit) bit mantissa), which is ok to represent any integer ranged in [-2^53, 2^53], inclusive.

While in the 64-bit computer, usually long long is better, but still there might be some situation that using "double" can perform faster. e.g, if you have hyper-threading enabled, both FPU and integer unit can be operating by different threads, at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The approach, as such, is quite reasonable for the time of writing. If the largest integer types that is portably available is `long`, and can only be relied on to be 32 bits wide, whereas the type `double` effectively gives you 52 bit integers, it is reasonable to use it.

The problem is that the program makes no checks for corner cases. If we plug the type `long` into it, it may overflow past `LONG_MAX`, triggering undefined behavior.

With the floating-point representation, another issue occurs: when the accumulated value becomes large enough, adding another 1.0 results in no change of value: the loop stops counting. This is actually less harmful than the `long` overflow; though it is still defective. It happens because beyond a certain range, the floating point type becomes too sparse to represent consecutive integers. The value `nc + 1` is not exactly representable in the `double` type, and gets rounded.

The program can be improved by adding a check for this situation: a check that difference between the new and old value is not 1.0, as expected. In this case, the program can emit a diagnostic and terminate, so that it doesn't produce an incorrect count.

A way to improve the program would be to extend its range using two `double`-s, both initialized to `0.0`.  When one of the values reaches its counting limit, its value is accumulated to the other, and it is cleared back to 0.0.  In this manner, the program can continue to count far beyond the integer range of `double`, though providing only an approximation of the count (good to about `DBL_DIG` significant figures).

Another issue with the program is that it doesn't distinguish end-of-file from error. When `getchar` returns `EOF`, either condition can be true; the `ferror` stream accessor can be used to distinguish which. The program will count bytes until an I/O error occurs, and then report that count without mentioning the event.

Lastly, the program neglects to return an exit status from `main`, so that it has no clear termination status.

The following is a test version of the proposed program in which the type of the `batch` and `batch_new` variables is altered to `float`.

This allows for simple empirical testing of the concept, using reasonably small small inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

/* count characters in input; SO version */
int main(void)
{
  double total;
  float batch; /* change me to double */

  for (total = 0.0, batch = 0.0; getchar() != EOF; ) {
    float batch_new = batch + 1.0; /* me too */
    if (batch_new - batch != 1.0) {
      total += batch;
      batch = 1.0;
    } else {
      batch = batch_new;
    }
  }

  if (ferror(stdin)) {
    printf("I/O error on standard input\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (total == 0.0)
    printf("%.0f (exact)\n", batch);
  else
    printf("%.*g (approx)\n", DBL_DIG, total + batch);

  return 0;
}
```

Runs:

```
~/test$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=$((15 * 1024)) | ./count
15360+0 records in
15360+0 records out
15728640 bytes (16 MB) copied, 0.293093 s, 53.7 MB/s
15728640 (exact)
~/test$ (dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=$((15 * 1024)) ; echo -n x) | ./count
15360+0 records in
15360+0 records out
15728640 bytes (16 MB) copied, 0.288816 s, 54.5 MB/s
15728641 (exact)
~/test$ (dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=$((16 * 1024))) | ./count
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
16777216 bytes (17 MB) copied, 0.343045 s, 48.9 MB/s
16777216 (exact)
~/test$ (dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=$((16 * 1024)) ; echo -n x) | ./count
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
16777216 bytes (17 MB) copied, 0.304446 s, 55.1 MB/s
16777217 (approx)
~/test$ (dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=$((16 * 1024)) ; echo -n xx) | ./count
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
16777216 bytes (17 MB) copied, 0.300321 s, 55.9 MB/s
16777218 (approx)
```

(The approx values are still exact because we are nowhere near the limit of the `double` type.)